# Cannot find module 'genfun' while installing node modules

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, package.json

I am facing one issue while installing node_modules. I am getting below error

Cannot find module ***genfun***

I removed `/node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` from my root. Still if I run `npm install` in the root directory, it is throwing above error. I'm not getting what I need to do. Please tell me the steps I need to do.

Thanks for your help :-)

[image]

Below one is my `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "Temporary Name",
  "version": "6.0.0",
  "license": "MIT License",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "serveProd": "ng serve --environment=prod",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^1.2.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^11.3.2",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "date-fns": "1.28.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
    "ng2-translate": "5.0.0",
    "ng2-validation": "4.2.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.3.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "0.3.1",
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "5.2.0",
    "@types/hopscotch": "0.2.28",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.3.0",
    "enhanced-resolve": "3.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "2.0.0",
    "tslint": "4.5.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: try first "npm i genfun --save" and after that try "npm install" 
May be this will help

Comment: @KaushikAndani I tried that, still not good results, even that one also throwing same issue regarding `genfun` missing

Comment: okay , can you please share your package.json?

Comment: @KaushikAndani I've updated my question with package.json file, please check once

Comment: i tried with above package.json and its work fine in my machine

Comment: Then is that the problem in `npm` and `nodejs` versions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177252/discussion-between-kaushik-andani-and-javascript-lover).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue

Previously my nodejs version is `v8.9.4`. Now I just updated to current version(at the time I'm posting this answer) i.e., `v8.11.3`